# eSun PETG outer wall delamination, random huge artifacting on some sides and fine printing on others

Tags: petg, delamination

Check [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/FixMyPrint/comments/ysa0ve/esun_petg_outer_wall_delamination_random_huge/) for larger versions of these pictures,

[image: Random image #1]

[image: Random image #2]

[image: Random image #3]

Using an Ender 5 Pro, printing at 0.28 mm lowest resolution.

As per that subs recommendation, I've tried the following with not a shred of difference:

- Different speeds down to 40 mm
- Temps from 230-250 °C
- Fans from 0-50 %
- Calibrated E step
- Changed retract before outer wall to off
- Outer wall flow 105 %
- Main flow to 105 %
- Top skin overlap to 50 %
- Ironing on
- Retrimmed Bowden tube
- New nozzle
- Cleaned out hot end
- Relevelling
- Also happened directly after dehydrating

Seems to be something completely transient to these settings as it happens in the same place every time regardless. Are these under-extrusion spots? Should the PETG have a bigger baby-stepped Z gap?

Also seems like the first layer and other layers print what should be a straight line into an angled line (see top delamination). Completely stumped.

Comment: You want our assistance, but you expect us to go to reddit to see your images?

Comment: Kyron, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE. Please note that SE sites are not regular forums, it is just questions and answers. A question must therefore need to contain all the information we need to answer it, linking to a forum for the images is not allowed, SE has its own dedicated Imgur web server where it stores your images as long as the SE sites live when you embed the images through the image button above the text editor of your question. We've embedded the images for you.

Answer (score 1):

Go a lot slower. 40 mm/s is near the max speed for PETG on a stock Creality bowden extruder **at 0.2 mm layer height**. You're aiming for nearly 50% more flow per unit distance, so you need to drop speed proportionally, down to about 25-30 mm/s.

If your problem is isolated to only certain spots, it's likely that those are the only spots where you actually achieve and maintain the requested flow versus slowing down and speeding up over and over. It's also possible that you have oozing during travel (especially travel inside the boundary of the part, if your slicer is doing that unretracted) or that the extruder is slipping during unretract, producing missing extrusions.